# How to count number of occurrence of each word in string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the following code to extract words from string input, how can I get the occurrence of each words too?

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+")
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(w => w)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() > 10)
                        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Regex.Split` you can use `string.Split` and get the count for each word like:

```
string str = "Some string with Some string repeated";
var result  = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .GroupBy(r => r)
                .Select(grp => new
                    {
                        Word = grp.Key,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    });
```

If you want to filter out those words which are repeated 10 times atleast then you can add a condition before `Select` like `Where(grp=> grp.Count >= 10)`

For output:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word: {0}, Count:{1}", item.Word, item.Count);
}
```

Output:

```
Word: Some, Count:2
Word: string, Count:2
Word: with, Count:1
Word: repeated, Count:1
```

For **case insensitive grouping** you can replace the current GroupBy with:

```
.GroupBy(r => r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

So your query would be:

```
var result = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .GroupBy(r => r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                .Where(grp => grp.Count() >= 10)
                .Select(grp => new
                    {
                        Word = grp.Key,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+")
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(w => w)
                        .Select(g => new {key = g.Key, count = g.Count()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Select` statement to keep the `IGrouping` which you can use to view both the keys and take a count of values.

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+")
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(w => w)
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 10);

foreach (var wordGrouping in words)
{
    var word = wordGrouping.Key;
    var count = wordGrouping.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a dictionary like this:

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+")
                 .GroupBy(w => w)
                 .Select(g => g.Count() > 10)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Or if you'd like to avoid having to compute the count twice, like this:

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+")
                 .GroupBy(w => w)
                 .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                 .Where(g => g.Count > 10)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
```

And now you can get the count of words like this (assuming the word "foo" appears more than 10 times in `input`):

```
var fooCount = words["foo"];
```