# File reading and words counting

Tags: c#

I want to read a file and then read a string of words or a sentance and count individually how many times those words occur in the file. Also I need to seperate the words that do not occur.
Example **Input**: 
  `filename.txt` 
 `Powerfull moon forest sky` 
Example **Output**: 
Powerfull: 2

 moon: 3

 forest: 4

 Not used: sky

I am kinda stuck in here and this is what I got

```
string filename = Console.ReadLine();
        StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(filename);
       
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] source = filename.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var matchQuery = from word in source
                         where word.ToLowerInvariant() == input.ToLowerInvariant()
                         select word;
        int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences(s) of the search term \"{1}\" were found.", wordCount, input);
```

Comment: I am giving a hint. You can use `group by` in select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count number of occurrence of each word in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227721/how-to-count-number-of-occurrence-of-each-word-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral ways to do it. One of them is group by as query as Arshad commented. You can also use dictionary to preserve your result if you read file line by line. Here is example, but you have to adjust it to yours requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967649/7226070

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting on whitespaces and punctuation (please, note, that we have a lot of them)
I suggest *matching*. If we define word as

> Word is non-empty sequence of letters

we can use a simple *regular expression* pattern:

```
 \p{L}+
```

and then you can preprocess file:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\p{L}+");

 var freqs = File
   .ReadLines(filename)
   .SelectMany(line => regex
      .Matches(line)
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(match => match.Value))
   .GroupBy(word => word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

Time to user query. Again, we match words and then find occurrencies with a help of `freqs`:

```
  var result = regex
    .Matches(Console.ReadLine())
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Select(word => 
       (word : word, 
        count : (freqs.TryGetValue(word, out int count) ? count : 0))) 
    .OrderBy(item => item.count == 0) // push all not used to the end
    .GroupBy(item => item.count > 0 ? item.word : "Not used")
    .Select(group => $"{group.Key} : {string.Join(", ", group)}"); 

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: I am getting an error trying to use this code:                                                            .Select(word => $"{(freqs.TryGetValue(word, out int count) ? count : 0)} occurrences(s) of {word} found");

Comment: @Aleksandar Yordanov: My bad, I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());` in the first fragment

Comment: This is really good but what if I wanted to have a "Not used" string and place all the words that aren't found in there instead of them appearing as 0 ?

Comment: @Aleksandar Yordanov: all you have to do is to change a bit the last `Select`: `.Select(word => freqs.TryGetValue(word, out int count) 
  ? $"{count} occurrences(s) of {word} found"
  : "Not used");`

Comment: Its not exactly how i need it, the output should be, i need to know which word hasn't been used not the null value Example Output:
Powerfull: 2
moon: 3
forest: 4
Not used: sky

Comment: @Aleksandar Yordanov:  I've edited the answer (the very last `.Select`)

Comment: I am really not trying to be picky but it's because of CodeGrade, the Not Used ones can they be written in one line like : Not used: Sky, Forest

Comment: @Aleksandar Yordanov: Well, as I can see you want to *group* all not found items, I've edited the last Linq query